# Why is shortcut with `map` not working?

Tags: ruby, ampersand

The two lines in this code:

```
p ["9", "6", "4"]
p %w(9 6 4)
```

return exactly the same array `["9", "6", "4"]`. But the first line with `map`:

```
p ["9", "6", "4"].map(&:to_i)
```

works fine, and the second one:

```
p %w(9 6 4).map{&:to_i}
```

gives:

```
syntax error, unexpected &
p %w(9 6 4).map{&:to_i}
```

I also tried to wrap it in bracers `(%w(9 6 4)).map(&:to_i)`, but had no luck. What is the problem with this code? `%w(...)` is a shortcut for array of strings. Why is it not working in the same way?

---

**UPD**

Ok, I got it. That's a stupid question, but I can't delete this question, since it has answers already. I voted to close it..

Comment: You have a difference in your map invocations. Look closely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is passing a raw block instead of a proc symbol.

Change

```
p %w(9 6 4).map{&:to_i}
```

to

```
p %w(9 6 4).map(&:to_i)
```

or

```
p %w(9 6 4).map {|n| n.to_i}
```

Comment: thanks. just a stupid mistake. I vote to close my question, since it doesn't make no sense for others. Thanks anyway!